# How to change minimized window size in Taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I would like to decrease minimized window size button in Windows 10 like Windows 7

First image is minimized window size button in Windows 7

https://ibb.co/gZ59TH

And second image is minimized window size button in Windows 10

https://ibb.co/hxc1ax

I would like to change minimized windows in Windows 10 
How can I do this?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to "change minimized windows", or are you trying to change the size of the application icons in the taskbar?

Comment: @music2myear Please see my attached files, I would like to change size of minimized window, size of minimized window in Windows 10 is about 155*35 and I would like to change it to for example 65*35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the Taskbar and select **Taskbar settings**

Scroll down to **Combine taskbar buttons** and select "**Always, hide labels**".

In this same window you can also choose to **Use small taskbar buttons**, which makes the icons themselves smaller.